# SQLite efficient update after select

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables :
Position with columns: id,x,y,entityID
Speed with columns : id,speedX,speedY,entityID

Only some entities have speed so i need an inner join somehow to between Position and Speed.

My problem is i want to update position with speed from Speed table for Position.entityID = Speed.entityID in one query.

Please , can you hit me with some SQL stuff?

Thank u!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical approach for update with join:

```
update Position 
  set x=(select speedx from Speed s where s.entityID=Position.entityID),
  set y=(select speedy from Speed s where s.entityID=Position.entityID)
where exists (select 1 from Speed where s.entityID=Position.entityID)
```

Performance vise this isn't optimal (inner queries), you may also want to evaluate "INSERT OR REPLACE" if that fits into your scenario.

Comment: Thank you! Works but is slow... how would be that INSERT OR REPLACE?